# Why Kubernetes returns unautorized error?

Tags: kubernetes

I used [Kubernetes document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/) to create a request for user certificate via API-server.

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
  name: myuser
spec:
  request: $(cat server.csr | base64 | tr -d '\n')
  usages:
  - digital signature
  - key encipherment
  - server auth
EOF
```

I generated the certificate, created the kubeconfig file and created the necessary role/rolebindings successfully. However, when I try to access the cluster, I get the below error. I am quite sure that the issue is with the above yaml definition; but could not figure out.

```
users error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

Any idea please?

Comment: that's the request. Have you signed it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems, the issue is with the "spec" part. It is user authentication not server authentication. Hence, "server auth" should be client auth.

```
spec:
  request: $(cat server.csr | base64 | tr -d '\n')
  usages:
  - digital signature
  - key encipherment
  - client auth
```

Comment: This also fixed it for me. I've seen it have "server auth" in tutorials on the web, but this tutorial i found includes both "server auth" and "client auth" and is a lot more comprehensive than others: https://medium.com/better-programming/k8s-tips-give-access-to-your-clusterwith-a-client-certificate-dfb3b71a76fe